# I am unable to evaluate my keras.Sequential model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Hi lately I started with tensorflow and I made my first model, but I couldn't evaluate it.
This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = train_images / 255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
    ])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

And this is the output with the ValueError:

```
Epoch 1/5
2020-09-26 14:38:33.631511: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 957us/step - loss: 1.6860 - accuracy: 0.7844
Epoch 2/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 937us/step - loss: 1.6222 - accuracy: 0.8415
Epoch 3/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 934us/step - loss: 1.6076 - accuracy: 0.8556
Epoch 4/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 951us/step - loss: 1.6019 - accuracy: 0.8604
Epoch 5/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 945us/step - loss: 1.5943 - accuracy: 0.8679

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mikele/Desktop/Python/tensor/NN.py", line 26, in <module>
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
  File "C:\Users\mikele\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikele\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1344, in evaluate
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "C:\Users\mikele\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1105, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "C:\Users\mikele\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 282, in __init__
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 60000
  y sizes: 10000
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

If you know what is causing this or how to fix this please respond with your ideas.
Thank you

Comment: This should be solved by a simple debuging, even by printing your data you would have see that your test data change its size. The message is straight forward. Theink about that next time, it will save you some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
    ])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

```
test_images = test_images / 255.0
```

This is the line where you made the mistake

If you are new in this domain, better use Spyder IDE. check the variable explorer to find the dimension

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The test dataset has been replaced with an invalid code.

Your code (14 line):

```
test_images = train_images / 255.0
```

Change like this:

```
test_images = test_images / 255.0
```

and you should evaluate by train-steps this code:

```
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out

I wrote there

```
test_images = train_images / 255.0
```

instead of

```
test_images = test_images / 255.0
```